# CloudKit sharing - Cannot convert userId to dsId due to an invalid userId

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am trying to use the new data sharing function of Apple CloudKit. I can successfully send a sharing link to other device. When I open it, I get share metadata (some hashes are truncated):

```
<
    CKShareMetadata: 0x170110b30; 
    shareID=<
        CKRecordID: 0x170234020;
        recordName=com.mentalfaculty.ensembles.zone.schema2, 
        zoneID=com.mentalfaculty.ensembles.zone.schema2:_c96e4c45c173bb2215138...
    >,

    participantType=PrivateUser, 
    Owner=<
        CKUserIdentity: 0x1700b8720;
        lookupInfo=<
            CKUserIdentityLookupInfo: 0x170664900;
            email=me@company.com
        >,
        cached=0,
        nameComponents=MyName,
        userID=<
            CKRecordID: 0x170229ac0;
            recordName=_c96e4c45c173bb2215138...,
            zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__
        >
    >,
    participantStatus=Pending,
    container=iCloud.com.company.app:Sandbox,
    rootRecordID=<
        CKRecordID: 0x17403a380;
        recordName=CDEFileSystemNode_/,
        zoneID=com.mentalfaculty.ensembles.zone.schema2:_c96e4c45c173bb2215138...
    >, 
    participantPermission=ReadWrite, 
    shareURL=https://www.icloud.com/share/...
>
```

However, when I try to accept the share, I get this error:

```
<
    CKError 0x170440120: "Partial Failure" (2/1011);
    "Failed to accept some shares";
    uuid = 1C3D8534-BE22-42D2-9EDD-...;
    container ID = "iCloud.com.company.app.ios.debug"; 
    partial errors: {
        https://www.icloud.com/share/... = <
            CKError 0x17025f6b0: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2006);
            server message = "Cannot convert userId to dsId due to an invalid userId. The userId cannot be used for this container and/or environment."
        >
    }
>
```

I have noticed that containerID in metadata is different from containerID in error message. containerID in metadata is the "real" one while containerID in error message is just an application bundle identifier.
My questions:

1. Is it normal that containerIDs are different?
2. How can this error be solved?

I can provide more info if needed.

NOTE: I am using Ensembles framework for saving data in cloud.

P.S. I have already watched WWDC 2016 session 226 a couple of times, looked into Ensembles examples and, of course, googled for hours. No success.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, the problem was with `containerID`. Changed `containerID` in iCloud settings (Xcode->Project Settings->Target->Capabilities-iCloud) so it would be the same as bundle identifier and it started working. I don't know whether it's a bug that share accept method uses different `containerID` (that method just uses bundle identifier) than is provided in metadata object.